# Four superheroes involved in an operation

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

A superhero X from DC universe and a superhero Y from Marvel universe decided to join hands and stop a cybercriminal. They named this operation as 'Uncaged' as a codeword for 'Coding'.

---

"*I will select a superhero from my universe to assist me. You too select a superhero from your universe to assist you*" said X.

"*Sure. Let us all change our names to codewords similar to how our operation is named*" replied Y.

"*That's a good idea. I will message you tonight after choosing my partner. You too decide your partner by that time*" concluded X.

---

Later that night, X messaged Y:
"*Hi Cabrio, I have selected Heritor as my partner for this operation.*"

Y replied:
"*Hi Cabrio, I have selected Cleanout as my partner for this operation.*"

---

***Who are the four superheroes involved in this operation?***

***How are the codewords derived?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The four superheroes are:

> Bruce Wayne and Arthur Curry, from DC (Batman and Aquaman), and Bruce Banner and Clint Barton from Marvel (Hulk and Hawkeye)

The encoding is like this:

> Take the consonants from the original word plus the vowels NOT in the original word. In the example, "Coding" becomes "Uncaged" as we take the consonants ("CDNG") and the absent vowels ("AEU" cause we have OI in coding), and anagram them all together ( becomes "Uncaged"). We can do the same with Cabrio, Heritor and Cleanout to obtain Bruce (both Bruces), Arthur and Clint.